# Are Chrome user-scripts separated from the global namespace like Greasemonkey scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, anonymous-function, userscripts

I know Greasemonkey scripts are <strike>automatically wrapped in anonymous functions</strike> isolated in some way in order to prevent them conflicting with scripts in the page.

Does the same happen with Chrome user-scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Greasemonkey scripts are [normally wrapped in an anonymous function](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/0ca46387f89955f083d4bc65bd70622568f79bbb/components/greasemonkey.js#L508).  And, [Chrome userscripts apparently are too](http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/renderer/extensions/user_script_slave.cc&q=src/chrome/renderer/extensions/user_script_slave.cc&type=cs&l=46).

But, more importantly, Greasemonkey scripts are *usually*<sup>1</sup> wrapped in an [XPCNativeWrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper) sandbox, while Google Chrome converts userscripts into extensions, and [they operate in an arena that Google calls an "isolated world"](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)<sup>2</sup>.

So, you don't need to wrap your script code in anonymous functions for security purposes, they're already protected.

Just beware that:

1. If you inject code directly into the page (create a `<script>` tag), then that code can be seen by the page's JS.
2. If you use `unsafeWindow`, then the page could theoretically follow it back and gain slightly elevated privileges.

The risk is very low, and I haven't been able to find any documented exploits in the wild.

~~~
Bottom line, scripts are isolated to different degrees in both browsers. (And not merely by being wrapped in anonymous functions.)

Greasemonkey has [a nice set of privileged features](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Category%3aAPI_Reference) available, in Firefox.  While userscripts in Chrome are much more restricted.

However, much of GM's functionality is restored to Chrome via use of the [Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo).

---

<sup>1</sup> As of [Greasemonkey version 1.0](http://www.greasespot.net/2012/08/greasemonkey-10-release.html) (August 24, 2012), the sandbox is controlled by [the `@grant` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant).  If the script runs with (or defaults to) `@grant none`, then the sandbox isn't used.  The script merely runs in a private scope and the normal `GM_`, API functions will not work.

<sup>2</sup> Doesn't that sound so much bigger/nicer than some nasty sandbox?  (^_^)

.

Comment: Thanks for the super informative answer! So I don't need to wrap my code in anonymous functions in Chrome or greasemonkey Userscript then right?

Comment: Actually both [Greasemonkey](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/0ca46387f89955f083d4bc65bd70622568f79bbb/components/greasemonkey.js#L508) and [Chromium](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/renderer/extensions/user_script_slave.cc&l=41) wrap userscripts inside anonymous functions (though Greasemonkey respects the @unwrap metadata key, which Chromium does not).

Comment: Ah, so they're wrapped in anonymous functions *and* sandboxed in Greasemonkey! [@unwrap docs](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40unwrap)

Comment: @Ventero, I stand corrected; thanks!  Since you did not make your own answer, I rolled your corrections into mine.

Comment: Is there any good reason to embed the function to the page? This will add to the pages global object... I ask because I have seen it done in a number of scripts and wondered the reason behind it.

Comment: @rlemon, There can be reasons to inject the script, although it is done too often with Chrome scripts and is best to avoid if you can. Ask a separate question if you wish to explore that issue further.