# how to change anchor onclick event

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4

I would like to change the following onclick event, from:

```
view_tree_element('subscription','45592063',1);
focusit('1_45592063',true)
```

to

```
onclick="show_dialog('feed_info_dialog',{subscription_id: 45592063}
```

i.e. get the number 45592063 from the original onclick event,

store it in a variable and change the anchor to the show_dialog event

How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. Hint: Post effort and code

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: because the first function redirects in the same window (and you have to go back to the initial page afterwards), while the second opens a popup, which is more convenient, you don't have to leave the page

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.
It replaces the onclick handlers if there are any. You can add a test for existence of "subscription" in the `onc` var

I store the ID in an attribute of the link itself

```js
var re = /'subscription','(\d+)'/; // a number in quotes after 'subscription',
window.onload=function() { // or addEventListener
  var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[onclick]");
  for (var i=0; i<links.length;i++) {
    var onc = links[i].onclick.toString();
    if (onc) {
      var id = onc.match(re);
      if (id) { // something found
        links[i].setAttribute("sub-id",id[1]);
        links[i].onclick = function() {
          show_dialog('feed_info_dialog',{subscription_id: this.getAttribute("sub-id")});
          return false; // cancel link
        }  
      }
    }  
  }
}
// this will of course be YOUR show_dialog
function show_dialog(a,b) { 
  console.log(a,b);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="view_tree_element('subscription','45592063',1);
focusit('1_45592063',true)">Click</a><br/>
<a href="#">No onClick</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('subscription','',1)">Click - no id</a><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="view_tree_element('subscription','55592063',1);
focusit('1_55592063',true)">Click</a>
```

Comment: looks good but it doesn't work,
I'm trying to create a greasemonkey script

I can't/don't want to override show_dialog, it's a function of the page

and the anchors are created dynamically, after the page has finished loading

Comment: I am not overriding show_dialog. You did not give me one so I made my own.

Comment: I added the code to a greasemonkey script and it doesn't work on the page I want it to: https://www.inoreader.com/dashboard

Comment: ok, I'll ask in greasemonkey forum, thanks a lot,
I'll write results here

Comment: I added the GM tag.

Comment: @mplungjan, please read the tag popup/excerpt when editing.  This is probably Greasemonkey 4.  There can be a big difference.

Comment: I used generic GM / better than none.

Comment: the problem should be with window.onload=function() {} because with console.log(onc) I get:

function onclick(event) { l('Tree pane','How-to guide'); }

which suggests that the links I want to modify are created afterwards I think, so I need another function I guess

Comment: You may use another load event - I wrote a self contained script

Comment: links[i].setAttribute("sub-id",onc.match(re)[1]); is the one failing because the code never reaches the next line links[i].onclick = function()

Comment: onc.match is null

Comment: I have added a test for it

Comment: great idea! still nothing is found yet and console.log(onc) returns only "tour" elements, so can you propose a function that waits somehow for my links to load?

Comment: it fetches only links on the tree view side pane and not the interesting ones on the right that are constructed dynamically

Comment: Use a setTimeout or find the event that greasemonkey triggers when loaded

Comment: I can't find out how to do either :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731209/window-onload-works-in-firefoxgreasemonkey-script-but-not-in-a-chrome-userscrip

Comment: addEventListener did the trick!
https://greasyfork.org/en/forum/discussion/comment/44345#Comment_44345

Comment: Care to explain the downvoting ? It will teach no one without a reason