# Why is script.onload not working in a Chrome userscript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts, script-tag

I want to load another script file, in a site, using a userscript. 
But, the `js.onload` event doesn't work correctly.

The userscript file:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Code highlight
// @description    Test
// @include        http://localhost/*
// @version        1.0
// ==/UserScript==

var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.src = "http://localhost/test/js/load.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
    js.onload = function(){
        console.log(A)
    }
```

the load.js file:

```
var A = {
    name:'aa'
}
```

In Chrome, the console outputs "undefined", but the load.js has loaded completely.

I tested it in Firefox, and it outputs `A` correctly.

Comment: Note that it only worked in FF+Greasemonkey because the `@grant` was defaulting to `none`.  As soon as you try to use any `GM_` API functions, the script would break on FF too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Never use `.onload`, `.onclick`, etc. from a userscript.**  (It's also poor practice in a regular web page).

The reason is that userscripts operate in a sandbox (["isolated world"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828021/331508)), and you cannot set or use page-scope javascript objects in a Chrome userscript or content-script.

Always use `addEventListener()` (or an equivalent library function, like jQuery `.on()`).  Also, you should set `load` listeners before adding `<script>` nodes to the DOM.

Finally, if you wish to access variables in the page scope (`A` in this case), you must [inject the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485650/331508) that does so.  (Or you could switch to Tampermonkey and use `unsafeWindow`, but [Chrome 27 is causing problems with that](http://tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q404).)

Use something like:

```
addJS_Node (null, "http://localhost/test/js/load.js", null, fireAfterLoad);

function fireAfterLoad () {
    addJS_Node ("console.log (A);");
}

//-- addJS_Node is a standard(ish) function
function addJS_Node (text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D                                   = document;
    var scriptNode                          = D.createElement ('script');
    if (runOnLoad) {
        scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);
    }
    scriptNode.type                         = "text/javascript";
    if (text)       scriptNode.textContent  = text;
    if (s_URL)      scriptNode.src          = s_URL;
    if (funcToRun)  scriptNode.textContent  = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';

    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (scriptNode);
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
addJS_Node (null, "http://localhost/test/js/load.js", null, fireAfterLoad);

function fireAfterLoad () {
    addJS_Node (null, null, myCodeThatUsesPageJS);
}

function myCodeThatUsesPageJS () {
    console.log (A);
    //--- PLUS WHATEVER, HERE.
}

... ...
```

Comment: @BrockAdams
    `scriptNode.addEventListener ("load", runOnLoad, false);` what is false here for?

Comment: @viditjain, See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).  In this case, adding an explicit `, false` is a coding style choice.