# How to import es6 module that has been defined in <script type="module"> tag inside html?

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

I am able to define a module in my html file me.html:

```
<script type="module" id="DEFAULT_MODULE">   
           import Atom from './atom.js';       
           console.log("definition of getAtom")
           export default function getAtom(){
            return new Atom('atom');
           }
           console.log("exported getAtom")
</script>
```

Also see

- https://blog.whatwg.org/js-modules
- https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/443#issuecomment-167639239

=> Is it possible to import that "anonymous" module to another module script in the same html file? Or to some "code behind"- JavaScript file that also has been loaded by the me.html file? The export seems to work; at least it does not throw any error.

For the import of the `getAtom` method I tried for example:

```
<script type="module">
    import getAtom from '.'; //this line does not work
    console.log("usage of getAtom")
    var atom = getAtom();             
</script>
```

I would expect some syntax like

```
 import getAtom;
 import getAtom from '.';
 import getAtom from window;
 import getAtom from './me.html';
 import getAtom from '.DEFAULT_MODULE';
```

However, none of these lines worked.

=>What is the correct syntax to reference the "anonymous" module if it is possible at all?

I use Chrome version 63.0.3239.108.

Related question:

[How to dynamically execute/eval JavaScript code that contains an ES6 module / requires some dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978809/how-to-dynamically-execute-eval-javascript-code-that-contains-an-es6-module-re)

Comment: Import from codebehind from a HTML file? I don't think so. This is ugly codding right there, I don't see any usages for a script tag with module type. It'll just make things messy.

Comment: Please see the related question for an example usage. I am open to less ugly alternatives if you know some.

Comment: There is now [a proposal to add a `name` attribute to `script` tags that could then be used to refer to them in `import` statements](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7600).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inlining ECMAScript Modules in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817297/inlining-ecmascript-modules-in-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, there is no way to import "anonymous" module, because "anonymous" module have no module specifier or individual url (its `import.meta.url` is just the html url as current spec). In theory it can be extended in the future, but I can not find the good use cases for such feature.

Comment: Adding `<script type="module">` tag at runtime allows to dynamically include ES6 modules. However, their `exports` can not be accessed. That makes it hard to apply the (results of the) dynamically included code. An alternative solution could be a future `eval` method  that supports `import` statements. Please see the above mentioned related question and let me know if there are currently better alternatives for dynamic code execution.

Comment: The use case would be for code that has been dynamically generated in the browser.  I'm working on an IDE/language that has its own AST that compiles to JavaScript using `@babel/generator` but am having trouble figuring out how to incorporate the result of this code with the rest of the app.

Comment: You may try data url or `createObjectURL` and assign the result url to `src` attribute.

Comment: Has anyone tried hax's data-url approach?