# How use export in an HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When I have extern javascript file with an export-statement how can I call this in an HTML ?

- An import in a `<script>` tag also doesn't work.
- an include over the `<head>` gives me a "Unexpected token export" error

For example:
my extern js-File

```
export function myFunction(text) { return text; }
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="myExternFile.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        console.log(myFunction("some text"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not expected behaviour of `export`, also you don't need `export` for such function call. Remove `export` and your code must work fine.

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982205/how-to-import-es6-module-that-has-been-defined-in-script-type-module-tag-ins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ECMAScript modules in browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) you can do it with `<script type="module">`

```
<script type="module">
  import {myFunction} from './myExternalFile.js';

  console.log(myFunction("some text"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function will work without the export. Just make sure to call it between the script tags.