# Access variables defined in script tag with type module?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a script tag inside my HTML with type module, and it exports a variable:

```
<script type="module">
  var life = 42;
  export { life };
</script>
```

How do I access `life` from other script tags or the Chrome console for debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import es6 module that has been defined in <script type="module"> tag inside html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982205/how-to-import-es6-module-that-has-been-defined-in-script-type-module-tag-ins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should be using [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) in separate js files and not embedded in an html file. I'm not sure if [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) works on html files. However, for a separate js file in another js file you can just use `import {life} from 'path/to/file'` to load the variables. If it's embedded in html and you use scripts in the same page, you do not need the `export` and you can access `life` simply by using the variable `life`. In fact, the `type="module"` actually prevents variables defined in the script tag from being accessed. If you want to access the variables on the same page then you should remove it. The same applies for the developer console on the page.

Comment: Right, my script tag is type="module" because I need to import other modules I've defined. But any top-level variables defined in a script tag that is of type module cannot be accessed by the Chrome console (it throws `ReferenceError: life is not defined`). That is why I tried to export the variable, but Chrome console does not allow imports.

Comment: Just remove the `type="module"` and it'll work properly. Let me edit that into the post.

Comment: If I remove `type="module"`, I cannot import other modules inside of the script tag. I should have phrased the question this way: Is there any way to access variables inside a module from the developer console?

Comment: If you're really desperate you can set them on the window object directly like `window.life = life`. But you should use separate js files.

Comment: Ah, I see, I can attach it to other global variables (including those in other normal script tags). This is probably bad design but it's enough for my debugging needs. Good idea! I will take it as the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. What i put on the global window object, inside a type module. Is not accessible in future, non-type="module" tags. So I am stuck on exactly this question.

Comment: No wait it works in the onload.

Comment: Eh, often it would be nice to have them in the same file. So "you should be using export in separate js files" is either an opinion or because it was built in a way that makes it harder to have them in separate files. It's a bummer IMO.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be highly ranked in SEO and the real answer from @Aplet123 is a little buried in the comments.

1. You cannot access variables across/outside of modules, this is the whole point. You can export/import but this won't work in the browser console.
2. You can attach any object to window in order to expose it globally. So adding `window.life = life` will expose `life` (or `window.life`) in the browser console.

This is a solid option when you're playing around or debugging issues.

This shouldn't be used in production except under limited circumstances – for example if you need to load JavaScript without access to the network (including through a ServiceWorker) or you want the code to be in one file to be easily inspected.

Comment: There are valid reasons to do that in production.

Comment: fair point, I edited my answer!