# EventListener cloning in userscript

Tags: javascript, clone, event-listener

I have this function:

```
function main() {
    var bottomArea = document.getElementsByClassName("bottom-area");
    for (var i = 0; i < bottomArea.length; i++) {
        var showDialogLink = document.createElement("a");
        showDialogLink.innerHTML = "link";
        showDialogLink.onclick = function(){showSelect(this);return false;};
        bottomArea[i].insertBefore(showDialogLink, bottomArea[i].childNodes[3]);
    }
}
```

So far the code works just fine. When I click the newly created link, it calls showSelect(this) function just fine.

The problem is there is another userscript/browser extension (which I don't have access to - it's not mine), which basically clones whole another div in which 'bottom-area' div is nested. This is all right too, but the problem is that it doesn't clone my function trigger and those newly cloned instances (I'm not really sure what is their nature) of that link do no longer trigger showSelect(this) function. Only the first one created by my userscript does.

Is there some way in which I should add my function trigger on my link, that will stay even after cloning/copying?

EDIT: I'll just edit to show html tree:
This is at the beginning:

```
<div>
<div class="bottom-area"></div>
</div>
```

My userscript adds a link with an onclick eventlistener on the 'a' tag:

```
<div>
<div class="bottom-area"><a>link</a></div>
</div>
```

The other userscript basically clones it (there is a textarea inside the div and its value gets cloned too), but without the eventlistener, so clicking on the cloned links no longer triggers my function.

EDIT2: If it helps, the userscript I'm creating is a reddit userscript. I'm adding small  functionality to commenting and adding a link right next to the 'reddiquette' link under the comment text field. That works with the pre-generated text field. However when I click 'reply' down the comment tree, the whole div together with text field, submit button and my link gets cloned under the comment I'm replying too, but my link no longer has the function trigger on itself.

Comment: Use event delegation.

Comment: If the elements are "cloned" using `.innerHTML`, you will loose all event handlers, since it serializes the elements and create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution may be to simply use HTML event attributes (instead of `addEventListener`), such as `<a onclick="dostuff();">link</a>`, because the attribute should be preserved during 'cloning'. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r9t5cpg/5/) (tested in Firefox 40) for an example.

Letting the code in the onclick attribute interact with your userscript may be be a little difficult [because it runs in a different JavaScript environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828021/1288130). Luckily there's plenty of possible workarounds, depending on your exact needs.