# Why does "@grant randominvalidsetting" activate the sandbox?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I saw [some code](https://gist.github.com/ryan-fisher/3809675) that used this setting to activate the sandbox:

```
@grant sandbox
```

When I run the following basic Greasemonkey script in Firefox:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   user12345678
// @include     http://example.com
// @version     1
// @grant       sandbox
// ==/UserScript==

console.log(window.toString());
```

It seems that the sandbox is setup:

```
[object XrayWrapper [object Window]]
```

...unlike when you use `@grant none`:

```
[object Window]
```

It appears to work just the same as adding `unsafeWindow` or `GM_log`, but I can't seem to find anything about this [in the documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block) (yes, I've searched). I even tested it with some gibberish:

```
@grant randominvalidsetting34234239482389482394
```

That had the same effect as putting `@grant sandbox` or a Greasemonkey function as the value.

If it is not in the documentation, is it actually valid? And if it isn't, why does it appear to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you hear that?  Nevertheless, it's true but I don't recommend it.

From [the `@grant` documentation](http://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) (not what was linked in the question):

> The **valid values** are the names of those GM_ prefixed values that you wish your script to be granted access to.

(Plus `none`, plus `unsafeWindow`.)

While using `sandbox` will work, for now, I prefer a value that's more "future proof", EG `GM_addStyle`.

As you can see from [Greasemonkey's source code (now superceded)](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/e9d947ca5a240ec9fe7779ad619dedaff7b1bbbd/components/greasemonkey.js#L68), unless the script is operating in `grant none` mode, it is always sandboxed ([wrapped in an XPCNativeWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828021/331508)), hence the `[object XrayWrapper [object Window]]` that you got.

This means that just about anything besides `none` for a `@grant` value will activate the sandbox, *for Greasemonkey, for now*, but it's not guaranteed to always work the same way for Greasemonkey, Scriptish, Tampermonkey, etc. So use one of the known valid values to activate your sandbox.

(And for maximum portability and to eliminate "time bomb code", I recommend always using the sandbox.)