# Attempt to modify HTMLTableRowElement.prototype

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have two methods, working nicely in couple of pages, but when it comes to a Greasemonkey script they fail for some reason, throwing an 'is not a function' error.
The very same code, while attached normally to the page, works perfectly.

```
HTMLTableRowElement.prototype.hideRow = function(){this.style.display = 'none'};
HTMLTableRowElement.prototype.showRow = function(){this.style.display = ''};
```

Error is appearing upon calling for one of these functions. Any clues?

Comment: Why are you trying to modify the prototype instead of just acting on the rows directly?

Comment: I know that using prototype isn't nesessary here, and indeed ended up with acting directly on the row. The reason for doing it initially, was simply attempt to try different approach. And now, it turns out to be useful, as it made me learn something important, with your help :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code doesn't work from a Greasemonkey script due to the GM script being in a different scope and (nominally) in a sandbox. See ["Why is window (and unsafeWindow) not the same from a userscript as from a script tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828021/331508) for more information and for workarounds (`@grant none` (maybe), or script injection, or `unsafeWindow`).

However, unless you are trying to alter existing code added by/to the page, **don't do things that way.**

Use jQuery's `.hide()`, `.show()`, or `.toggle()`.

Or create a class using `GM_addStyle()`, EG:

```
GM_addStyle (".GM_hide {display: none !important;}");
```

and use DOM functions to add or remove the class as desired. EG:

```
//--- Select the 2nd row of the first table
var someRow = document.querySelector ("table tr:nth-of-type(2)");

someRow.classList.add    ("GM_hide");
someRow.classList.remove ("GM_hide");
someRow.classList.toggle ("GM_hide");
```