# Code working in browser console but not in tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, console, tampermonkey

I am trying to run the following block of code on https://lichess.org/uZIjh0SXxnt5.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].href.includes("WaisKamal") && x[i].classList.contains("user_link")) {
        x[i].innerHTML = '<span class="title" data-title="GM" title="Grandmaster">GM</span> ' + x[i].innerHTML;
    }

    if(x[i].href.includes("WaisKamal") && x[i].classList.contains("text")) {
        x[i].innerHTML = '<span class="title" data-title="GM" title="Grandmaster">GM</span> ' + x[i].innerHTML;
        console.log(x[i]);
    }
}
```

I am using tampermonkey to automate the process. When the page loads, the first if statement runs correctly, but not the second one. However, when I run the second one from the browser console, it works fine.

Here is what the script does in more detail (I want to add those orange "GM"s):

**Without the script**

[image]

**With the script**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923992/code-from-bookmarklet-works-in-console-but-not-in-my-tampermonkey-script) but it didn't solve my problem.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `x`? ??

Comment: Sorry I missed it, I will update the question.

Comment: The interface on the right of the board (where you want the missing "GM" to go) doesn't appear for me at that link you posted, on any browser - it shows a list of moves instead, so I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Maybe there's a delay before the class gets added?

Comment: [@CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) I am using the latest version of chrome and it is working fine.

Comment: [@Vasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315419/vasan) the class never gets added, even after waiting for some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of that page is loaded dynamically (AJAX-driven), which means that your script will normally finish running long before the nodes, that you are interested in, appear in/on the page.

You must use AJAX-aware techniques such as `waitForKeyElements` or `MutationObserver`.

Here's **a complete Tampermonkey script** that illustrates the process:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Lichess.org, Glorify select users
// @match    *://lichess.org/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements ("a[href*='WaisKamal']", spiffifyLink);

function spiffifyLink (jNode) {
    var oldHtml = jNode.html ();
    var newHtml = '<span class="title" data-title="GM" title="Grandmaster">GM</span> ' + oldHtml;
    jNode.html (newHtml);
}
```

---

See [this other answer for more information about choosing and using `waitForKeyElements` and/with jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site).

Comment: I would vote a dozen times if possible. Thanks a lot!