# My Code works the in Firefox console but not in Tampermonkey? (not a timing issue)

Tags: javascript, firefox, tampermonkey

I am trying to write a Tampermonkey userscript that uses a `<canvas>` to combine pictures into a single image and then auto downloads it.

My script code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Picture Download
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Picture Download
// @author       Oray
// @match        https://www.example.com/*
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js
// @grant        unsafeWindow
// ==/UserScript==
(function(){
  function GM_wait(){
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined'){
      window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100);
    }else{
      unsafeWindow.jQuery(function() { letsJQuery(unsafeWindow.jQuery); });
  }}
  GM_wait();

  function letsJQuery($){
$('html[lang] > body').prepend('<canvas id="cve"></canvas>');
      var img1 = new Image();
      var img2 = new Image();
      var combined = new Image();
      var nloaded = 0;
      var combinedx;
      var filename;
      var e;
      function checkload(event){
        nloaded++;
        if (nloaded < 2){
          return;
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById('cve');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = img1.width;
        canvas.height = img1.height + img2.height;
        context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
        context.drawImage(img2, img1.width / 2 - img2.width / 2 , img1.height);
        combinedx = canvas.toDataURL('data/gif');
        filename = 'myimage.png';
        var lnk = document.createElement('a');
        lnk.download = filename;
        lnk.href = combinedx;
          e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
          e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false,false, 0, null);
          lnk.dispatchEvent(e);
      }
      img1.onload = checkload;
      img1.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
      img1.src ="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81pNr82OTgL._SX679_.jpg";
      img2.onload = checkload;
      img2.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
      img2.src = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31W%2BDml7GsL.jpg";
  }
})();
```

**...works in the console but doesn't as a Tampermonkey script.**

Why?

---

---

Editor's note:  By the original title, this would be a very common problem due to AJAX timing ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50548838/code-working-in-browser-console-but-not-in-tampermonkey)).  But this question covers a different, rarer cause with the same base symptom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the browser console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), you should see errors like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'initMouseEvent' on 'MouseEvent': parameter 4 is not of type 'Window'.

Or:

> TypeError: Argument 4 of MouseEvent.initMouseEvent does not implement interface Window.

That's because `window` has the wrong context inside your userscript in this line:

```
e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false,false, 0, null);
```

If you had used `unsafeWindow` it would work in the script (but not in the console).

If you use `e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true);` it will work in both.

**BUT,**  [`initMouseEvent` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent), best to use [the `MouseEvent()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent); see the code below.

Also:

1. That `(function(){` has been superfluous clutter for years.  Userscripts are wrapped by default and fire after jQuery's ready, by default, on all major script engines.
2. Likewise, the `letsJQuery` rigmarole is completely unnecessary.
3. After calls like `canvas = document.getElementById('cve');`, you need to make sure the variable is defined before using it.  See the code below.

So, here is **the working userscript with those adjustments:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Picture Download
// @match       *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $ */

//$('html[lang] > body').prepend ('<canvas id="cve"></canvas>');
$('html > body').prepend ('<canvas id="cve"></canvas>');
var img1 = new Image ();
var img2 = new Image ();
var combined = new Image ();
var nloaded = 0;
var combinedx;
var filename;
var e;

img1.onload = checkload;
img1.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img1.src = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81pNr82OTgL._SX679_.jpg";
img2.onload = checkload;
img2.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img2.src = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31W%2BDml7GsL.jpg";

function checkload (event) {
    nloaded++;
    if (nloaded < 2) {
        return;
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById ('cve');
    if (!canvas) {
        console.warn ("No canvas.");
        return;
    }
    var context = canvas.getContext ('2d');
    canvas.width = img1.width;
    canvas.height = img1.height + img2.height;
    context.drawImage (img1, 0, 0);
    context.drawImage (img2, img1.width / 2 - img2.width / 2, img1.height);
    combinedx = canvas.toDataURL ('data/gif');
    filename = 'myimage.png';
    var lnk = document.createElement ('a');
    lnk.download = filename;
    lnk.href = combinedx;

    e = new MouseEvent ("click");
    lnk.dispatchEvent (e);
}
```

Comment: I voted for you but I'm new here
my vote is not yet accepted

Comment: This was only one part of the puzzle for me. In my case it was also necessary to pass `view: unsafeWindow` in the MouseEvent's options argument (and add the `// @grant unsafeWindow` in the userscript header), because the site (YouTube Music) expected the view property to implement properties that weren't present due to the [isolation by userscript managers.](https://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow#Description)