# How replacing Element prototype method?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey-4

What should I do to make it work in greasemonkey?:

```
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
```

Now, when I use this:
`document.body.attachShadow({mode:"closed"}).innerHTML = "dec";`

Is this bug:

> Error: Permission denied to access object

What should I do to make the application use the substituted method?

**EDIT (MORE INFO):**

Firefox Nightly 62.0a1 (2018-06-18) (64 bity)

Greasemonkey 4.4.0

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 124585
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include http://kind-clarke-ced7cb.bitballoon.com/
// ==/UserScript==


Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
console.log("US work");
```

Tested page:
http://kind-clarke-ced7cb.bitballoon.com/

```
<div id="test" style="border: 1px solid silver;">xxx</div>

<div id="info">wait 4 sec...(so that UserScript can load itself before)</div>
   <script>
setTimeout(()=>{
  document.querySelector("#test").attachShadow({mode:"closed"}).innerHTML = "dec";
  document.querySelector("#info").innerHTML += `<br/>run: document.querySelector("#test").attachShadow({mode:"closed"}).innerHTML = "dec";`;
}, 3000);

setTimeout(()=>{
  document.querySelector("#info").innerHTML += `<br/>shadowRoot of #test is: ${(document.querySelector("#test").shadowRoot)}`;
}, 4000);
    </script>
```

Now this substitution of the attachShadow method simply does not work.

shadowRoot of #test return null but should be `[object ShadowRoot]`, because UserScript forces it.

Comment: Works for me. Add a complete userscript (with the metadata header) and an URL that demonstrates the problem (e.g. example.com). Also specify which version of FF and GM you are using.

Comment: Which FF version are you using ?

Comment: @wOxxOm
I've added info and the whole code.

Comment: @VigneshRaja  Firefox Nightly 62.0a1 (2018-06-18) (64 bity)

Answer (score 0):

The `shadowdom` is disabled by default from FF version 59. To enable it, preferences need to be modified.

Go to `about:config` -> Search for `dom.webcomponents.shadowdom.enabled` -> Double click it to toggle the boolean value (set it to `true`) -> Reload your page.

[MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow)

Now the replacement will work. Tested in `Firefox Quantum 60.0.2 (64 bit)` and `Firefox Nightly 62.0a1 (64 bit)`

But the shadow element cannot be seen in the HTML tree while inspecting via `Inspect Element`. A bug has also been reported in [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1205323)

Only an info message stating `Shadow DOM used in [site-link] or in some of its subdocuments.` will be logged in the console. (Message shown only in Nightly version)

**EDIT :**
After a little digging, found that using `unsafeWindow` may solve your problem. [Little detail about unsafeWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824697/why-is-window-and-unsafewindow-not-the-same-from-a-userscript-as-from-a-scrip)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Unnamed Script 124585
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include  http://kind-clarke-ced7cb.bitballoon.com/
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.Element.prototype._attachShadow = unsafeWindow.Element.prototype.attachShadow;
unsafeWindow.Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
console.log("US work");
setTimeout(()=>{
  document.querySelector("#test").attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = "dec";
  document.querySelector("#info").innerHTML += `<br/>run: document.querySelector("#test").attachShadow({mode:"closed"}).innerHTML = "dec";`;
}, 1000);

setTimeout(()=>{
    document.querySelector("#info").innerHTML += `<br/>shadowRoot of #test is: ${(document.querySelector("#test").shadowRoot)}`;
}, 2000);
```

The substitution didn't work as the `mode` is `closed`. Change it to `open`.

Comment: But I use Firefox Nightly 62.0a1. Problem is with Greasemonkey, not with ShadowDom  itself.

Comment: Have you enabled those preference settings ?

Comment: Yes. ShadowDom works fine. Problem is in it, that `
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;` not create _attachShadow, and that Element.prototype.attachShadow in not replacing through new funkcion. Its happens in UseScript.

Comment: @lukaszpolowczyk updated the answer.. now it may work. please check.

Comment: `unsafeWindow` should not make a difference in `@grant none` mode. (Which didn't exist when that Q&A was written.)

Comment: @VigneshRaja
With unsafeWindow is Error: `Permission denied to access object` when run function attachShadow. Henceforth page is no access to function attachShadow. It is blocked.