# How to retrieve a global context variable from a string using GreaseMonkey/ViolentMonkey?

Tags: javascript, firefox, window, greasemonkey

When trying to retrieve a variable defined in global context (usually `window`) from a string in Javascript, I know that you can simply do it like this:

```
var testVar = 123;
console.log(window["testVar"]); // logs "123"
```

However, inside a content-injected userscript I wrote for ViolentMonkey this simply returns `undefined`, seemingly because the global context works differently there than in an usual page script. I tried different ways of accessing the global context:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @namespace   *
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @inject-into content
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var testVar = 123;

console.log(testVar); // logs "123"
console.log(window.testVar); // logs "undefined"
console.log(window["testVar"]); // logs "undefined"
console.log(this["testVar"]); // logs "undefined"
console.log(unsafeWindow["testVar"]); // logs "undefined"
```

All of which are not working. Is there some way I can access the global context inside an userscript, or even a different way to retrieve a variable from a string?

What I'm trying to achieve at the end is to instantiate a class object from one of a bunch of externally loaded classes where the class used depends on the site URL.

If possible, I'd like to avoid defining the classes in namespaces, which would be refactoring hell for me, or the use of `eval` for obvious reasons.

EDIT: I've also scouted through the tested context objects from above in the console, none of which contains any trace of the variable I'm trying to retrieve.

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd. `window.testVar` should work. I thought it might be a timing problem and original posted an answer saying to add `@run-at document-end`, but then I checked the [ViolentMonkey documentation](https://violentmonkey.github.io/api/metadata-block/#run-at) and it said that's the default, so... Huh.

Comment: I suppose it's always possible the page doesn't define it until sometime after `DOMContentLoaded`. You could poll for it: `check(100);
function check(remaining) {
    if (typeof window.testVar !== "undefined") {
        // ...run your code...
    } else if (remaining === 0) {
        // give up
    } else {
        setTimeout(check, 50, remaining - 1);
    }
}`

Comment: Not quite sure how this would be a timing issue, I supposed the instructions would still run synchronously inside an userscript. I did a quick test though, putting the logging instruction inside a timeout function with a 5000ms delay, but it still logs `undefined`.

Comment: That does suggest it's something else... :-|

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using?
There are some behavioural differences between Chrome & Firefox. For example:

> In Chrome, `eval()` always runs code in the context of the
>   content script, not in the context of the page.
>
> In Firefox:
>
> - If you call `eval()`, it runs code in the context of the content script.
> - If you call `window.eval()`, it runs code in the context
>     of the page.
>
> source: [Using eval() in content
>   scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Using_eval_in_content_scripts)

`var` is global within its scope.

Content scripts run in their own scope. Otherwise page script can run functions in content script and thus browser and create a security hole.

AFAIK GreaseMonkey/ViolentMonkey/TamperMonkey sandbox each user-script, while FireMonkey (Firefox only) uses the dedicated userScript API which creates a secure scope for each user-script.

Therefore, `var testVar = 123;` is only visible within the script content scope.

`window` object is the overall object that contains both the user scope and page scope.

For example:

```
var testVar = 123;
console.log(testVar);         // logs "123"
console.log(window.testVar);  // logs "undefined"



window.testVar = 456;

console.log(testVar);         // logs "123"
console.log(window.testVar);  // logs "456"
```

*Note: tested with FireMonkey*

> trying to retrieve a variable defined in global context (usually
>   window)

For getting a variable defined in page context (as oppose to setting it), there are a few options which depends on the situation:

- using [unsafeWindow](https://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) (GM/VM/TM)
- [Content Script Injection](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection)
- Using  tag to inject code into the page context/scope (also read [Why is window (and unsafeWindow) not the same from a userscript as from a  tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824697/why-is-window-and-unsafewindow-not-the-same-from-a-userscript-as-from-a-scrip))
- Event Listeners can be used to trigger communication between content scope and page scope in case data needs to be exchanged

### @require

`@require` should also be injected into the same context/scope as the user-script that it has required it, which is the content scope, by the script managers.

In order to answer more precisely, the actual code has to be seen.

Comment: I'm using Firefox (added to tags), AFAIK that's even the only browser running Violentmonkey. I'm also familiar to the concept of the userscript sandbox and how it's different to page context. My question is not about page context though; when I wrote "global context" I was talking about the userscript's top-level context. And while `window.testVar = 456;` might work for in-script declared variables, it won't work for classes that I'm importing via `@require`, which is what I need in the end.

Comment: @StrikeAgainst I will update my post about `@requrie`.

Comment: Regarding your edit, that is still no news to me. I don't think my actual code will be very helpful in this, as we already have a short example here showcasing what's not working right now. What about trying to define a class in an external script for yourself, `@require` it in the userscript and then create a class object through the class' name? Does this work for you? I think our discussion here is kinda straying away from the actual problem, to be honest.