# UserScript init trouble

Tags: javascript, initialization, tostring, userscripts

Now, I'm working with userscript for a browser game. And I have some problems with **sandbox** and  **initialization**.
As a solution, I found a way with **creating a new element** (script) and **inserting the object in element**.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.innerHTML = "var Class = { ... }";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

But I have a very large object and convert it to a string rather problematic and time consuming.
I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
addToStorage : Function,
getFromStorage : Function,
getID : Function
settings : Object,
langs : Object,
init : Function,
version : Number,
author: String
}
```

Any ideas, how to convert it to *string* or insert into global *window*?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks for all. I have found the solution for problem.
I use this:
`(function (fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script); // run the script
    document.body.removeChild(script); // clean up
})(function() {
  // here is any code
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, you can use the `.toSource()` function on objects.  So the answer is ditch Chrome and switch to Firefox. (^_^)

But assuming you don't want to do that, the answer gets messy, as even `JSON.stringify()` won't work if the object as function properties, like yours does.

So, you can inject your object source using [a multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/805107/331508) (see the link for a variety of techniques).

Or you can make or use a an object stringifier like `objToString`, below.  Warning, `objToString` is just a quick and dirty first attempt, you might be smarter to grab something like [JavaScript var_export](http://phpjs.org/functions/var_export:578), instead.

```
var myObjX =  {
    someFunction:   function () {console.log ("foo");},
    settings:       {init: 2},
    langs:          {a: "En", b: "Jp"},
    version:        99,
    author:         "Anon"
}

function objToString (obj) {
    var str = '{ ';
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty (p) ) {
            str += p + ': ';
            switch (typeof obj[p]) {
                case "object":
                    str += objToString (obj[p]);
                    break;
                case "string":
                    str += '"' + obj[p] + '"';
                    break;
                default:
                    str += obj[p];
                    break;
            }
            str += ',\n';
        }
    }
    return str.slice (0, str.length-2) + ' }';
}

var script          = document.createElement("script");
script.type         = "text/javascript";
script.textContent  = "var injectedX = " + objToString (myObjX);
document.body.appendChild (script);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`unsafeWindow` object](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) to break out of the greasemonkey sandbox.

To break out of Chrome's isolated environment, according to [Are Chrome user-scripts separated from the global namespace like Greasemonkey scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6617361/1048572) you need to insert a `<script>` element into the DOM.

You shouldn't store that script's source in an escaped string, better take a JS object and stringify it. For plain ones, you can use `JSON`, for more complex things put everything into a function and call `.toString()` on that:

```
function moduleClosure(global) {
    // do something
    return some object
}
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.innerText = "var Class = "+moduleClosure+"(window);";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: @PointedEars, why the downvote?  Injecting function code is close to standard practice for Chrome userscripts.